# Query in Mongodb throws a org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I am trying using mongoDB in spring. When I was trying to query the users with the function `findUserByUserName`like this:

```
@Repository("usersDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        mongoTemplate.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserByUserName(String userName)
    {
        return mongoTemplate.findOne(
                    new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(userName)), User.class);
    }
}
```

It throws a exception like this:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Parameter org.springframework.data.mapping.PreferredConstructor$Parameter@d1c79025 does not have a name!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:248) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:273) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:253) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readMap(MappingMongoConverter.java:1047) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:233) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1388) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1335) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:335) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:297) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:253) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:202) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:198) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:86) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2782) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2399) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:2191) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:716) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:704) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
at com._4paradigm.dlp.accountservice.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.findUserByUserName(UserDaoImpl.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
at com._4paradigm.dlp.accountservice.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$817c0b14.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at com._4paradigm.dlp.accountservice.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4c9ee824.findUserByUserName(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com._4paradigm.dlp.accountservice.service.impl.GroupServiceImpl.retrieveGroupInfo(GroupServiceImpl.java:232) ~[classes/:na]
at com._4paradigm.dlp.accountservice.controller.GroupController.retrieveGroupInfo(GroupController.java:110) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

and I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Please post your User class definition.

Comment: I upgraded to Java 21 and to SpringBoot 3.2.0 and for some reason my tests for a certain Document kept on failing with a similar error. I use lombok and turns out because I forgot a no argument constructor to the document whose tests were all failing. No idea why it decided to pop its head now with the upgrade but it did. I'm really surprised with previous SpringBoot version I was using it hadn't shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `@NoArgsConstructor` to the object I was querying and **every other directly/transitively linked object** fixed the problem for me